# Is it possible to drag a view out of the scene dock into its own XIB?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

Is it possible to drag a UIView *out* of the [scene dock](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddViewsToDock.html) of a UIViewController in the Storyboard into its own XIB file? Or do you have to do it "manually" (either by re-creating the view in a new XIB or text-editor surgery on the Storyboard XML)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, using Assistant Editor.

First, create a new empty .xib file. Then open Assistant Editor. On one side let the .xib file, and on the other storyboard. Then just drag and drop the scene dock.
Here's screenshot:

[image: Drag and Drop]

Comment: Aha! The trick though is to create the blank XIB, then *delete its root level view* before dragging the Supplementary view from the Scene Dock.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to tell to delete what you have there :)
I'll update the answer